# Can't connect to Google-Cloud mysql instance from flex instance with .netcore using .pfx file

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, pfx

I have created a new website using .netcore 2.1 using the google-cloud mysql instance.  I created a .pfx file for my client certificates from google-cloud and I can connect and run my website successfully from my localhost and connect to the google-cloud mysql instance using my .pfx file.  When I publish this to the google-cloud flex, my website runs but I can't connect to my mysql instance.  I get the following errors:

Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No such device or address) ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address     at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)     at System.Net.Dns.ResolveCallback(Object context)

How do I setup my .pfx file / and or ssl correctly to work from within the flex environment?

I was instructed by Cloud support to add 0.0.0.0/0 to my connections, and to update my app.yaml to have 
beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: "responsive-amp-xxxxxxxx:us-central1:databaseinstancename=tcp:3306"

and to update my connection string host name to my database instance name, which did not fix the issue.

I verified that my certs.pfx file is getting copied to the bin folder and using logs I verified that the file existed and my connection string and app.yaml is correct.

The only way I can get it to work is if I removed the need for an ssl certificate and switched it to allow connections that are not secured.

EDIT:
Here is my connection string: Uid=xxxxuser;Pwd=secret;Host=255.255.255.255;Database=mydb

Comment: What's your connection string?

Comment: I've had success using Unix Domain Sockets, e.g., see this documentation I wrote for using Google Cloud SQL from AppEngine: https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/cloud/gcp/#google-appengine

Comment: Thanks for responding Bradley, I will give the sample a look.  I edited my post and added the basics of my connection string.

Comment: Is your Host actually set to 255.255.255.255, or did you change that to protect the address in your question?

Comment: I changed it to protect the address.